# Unexpected results while replacing single characters in a text file

Tags: string, windows, batch-file, replace, cmd

My batch file:

```
@ECHO off

(FOR /f "delims=" %%i in (source.txt) DO (
    SET "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    SET "line=!line:Ć=F!"
    SET "line=!line:Ç=G!"
    SET "line=!line:Ň=R!"
    SET "line=!line:Ô=T!"

    ECHO.!line!
    endlocal
))>"output.txt"
```

My source.txt file:

```
ĆÇŇÔ
```

Expected output.txt file:

```
FGRT
```

Current output.txt file:

```
FFRR
```

My question is: what's wrong here?

Comment: Chances to find Unicode normalization experts in batch-file/CMD tags are low... If you can't rewrite it in some other language (even PowerShell) you may want to start reading on string normalization and how cmd deals with string comparison yourself. Possibly check other SE sites if similar question is appropriate there (it is borderline with being off-topic on SO).

Comment: I guess, your `source.txt` is encoded in Unicode (16bit). `cmd` tries it's best to "translate" it into 8bit Ansi, but you lose half of the "address space". That means, more than one Unicode-character "translates" to a single Ansi-character. But it gets even worse: to "translate" it, the codepage (see the `chcp` command) is used, so on different computers, you might get different results. On my computer with `type source.txt`, the file looks like `─å├ç┼ç├ö`, saved as Ansi it looks like `CÃNÈ` (note: different from your `ĆÇŇÔ`)

Comment: That said, `cmd` can't read Unicode (but curiously can write it (`cmd /u`) in special cases). If you need to work with Unicode/UTF files, switch to another (programming)language. As far as I know, PowerShell should be able to handle it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thank you for you comment - I did not know this will be so complicated... :/ I thought that such simple replacement in Batch file would be enough to do this job, I do not know how to use PowerShell.

Comment: @Stephan Thank you for you comment. My main aim was to convert `*.bas` file which is a text file filled with Atari Basic code - my problem was that all comments (texts after `rem` commands) were written with usage of  [ATASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATASCII) inverted characters and they are visible as these "weird characters" in `*.bas` file. I noticed that all other letters in these "inverted" comments are converted without problems but G and T are not / F and R are duplicated.

Comment: You could try to `chcp 1252` beginning of your script.

Comment: Here is an example of one simple original line code with comment from `*.bas` file: `100 REM ĐŇÉÎÔ` which should be converted to `100 REM PRINT` but now it is converted as `100 REM PRINR`.

Comment: Once upon a time, I tried out a notepad replacement software named, `NotePad++`, _(hated it)_, however, my recollection is that it should open and recognize ATASCII files and you should be able to use its search/replace facility and save it as ASCII too.

Comment: @Gerhard I've added simple `CHCP 1252 > NUL` line at the start of my batch and now it works - thank you so much for your comment! I'm new SO user: how can I mark your post as the answer? PS. I'm a little confiused as my Windows system codepage is already set to 1252 - why did I need to add this in batch?

Comment: @Compo I've already tried N++ but I couldn't find any option to correctly open my source file.

Comment: No need to mark anything. I only posted a comment and not an actual answer. Glad it helped. I will post an answer later to explain the code pages. On my mobile now so a bit difficult to post a proper answer.

Comment: What is output when you type `chcp` into a Command Prompt window?

Comment: @aschipfl: Now I'm even more confused as it shows 852 for me... :o

Comment: @Gerhard: Maybe for you it was "just a comment" but for me it was the solution I used. :D Anyway I'm still waiting for your "proper answer" to decide which post should be marked as the answer to my question. :)

Comment: @Lex, you can of course answer your own question, but if you want to do so, please post it as an answer rather than adding it to the question…

Comment: @aschipfl: Ah, I see. Using of Stack Overflow is more complicated than I thought. :D Thank you for your comment - I'll fix my post.

Comment: @Lex, you can only [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) a single answer (even your own); however, you can [vote on](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) multiple ones (except your own) as soon as you have got enough reputation; just visit the [help] for more information…

Comment: @aschipfl: Yes, now I know, but, at first, writing my own answer, especially if it was based on other people answers / comments seemed a bit weird / unfair to me. And accepting my own answer in such case sounds unacceptable to me as it looks similar to the case where some group of people does "all the dirty job" but someone else is honored - I do not like such situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `source.txt` is not saved as Unicode, your issue may be related to the codepage at the time you run your loop.

The following example switches to codepage `1252`, *`West European Latin`*, (as also suggested in the comments by Gerhard), if not that already. *Although I'd assume codepage `850`, `Multilingual (Latin I)` should work equally well*. *(Just change to the codepage required by replacing `1252` on lines `7`, and `8`, as necessary).*

```bsh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
If Not Exist "source.txt" GoTo :EOF
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('2^> NUL Set _cp') Do Set "%%G="
For /F Tokens^=* %%G In ('"%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com"'
) Do For %%H In (%%G) Do Set "_cp=%%~nH"
If Not %_cp% Equ 1252 (Set "_cpc=TRUE"
    "%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com" 1252 1> NUL)
(For /F UseBackQ^ Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ("source.txt") Do (
    Set "line=%%G"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Set "line=!line:Ć=F!"
    Set "line=!line:Ç=G!"
    Set "line=!line:Ň=R!"
    Set "line=!line:Ô=T!"
    Echo=!line!
    EndLocal)) 1> "output.txt"
If Defined _cpc "%SystemRoot%\System32\chcp.com" %_cp% 1> NUL
```

*Please note that using a `For` loop like this, will remove any blank lines from the output*

Comment: I've just added one simple `CHCP 1252 > NUL` line at the start of my batch and now it works - I hope it's ok as well? PS. Do you know what's the reason it is needed? I'm confused as my Windows system codepage was already set to 1252.

Comment: Well, is seems that Command Prompt window shows 852 - so here is the reason why I needed this fix.

Comment: Sorry, but that cannot be correct, it must not already be codepage `1252`, if that command alone fixes your issue. _(now proven in your subsequent comments, yours was `852`)_.

Comment: Please note @Lex, that the code above determines the current codepage, saves it, changes to the new one, if it isn't that already, performs your commands and then returns the codepage back to the point it was prior to the commands. This way you're only changing the codepage for the intended purpose, and not for the rest or the script/session, _(which is what will happen if you just add `ChCp 1252 > NUL` at the start)_. BTW, if my answer actually solves your issue, and as it is the only answer, you should mark it as accepted, _(it helps both the site, and future readers)_.

Comment: After running my "fixed" batch file (with only `CHCP 1252 > NUL`) the same command prompt still shows 852 (not 1252) so I think it's enough for my needs. :)

Comment: It's enough @Lex, if you don't care about using something robust, which does not rely on the `%PATH%`, and `%PATHEXT%` variables, _(both easily, frequently and incorrectly modified)_. Nonetheless, as my answer 100% works, contains the exact part which you've admitted fixes the issue, and is the only one posted. Please mark it as accepted, and use the site as it was intended to be used.

Comment: As I'm new to Stack Overflow I have additional question about marking the answers: can I mark this way more than one post? I'm asking this because I'm still waiting for the answer from @Gerhard he promised me and I used his comment as my primary solution so he definitely deserves to be marked.

Comment: Gerhard's comment adds nothing whatsoever to my answer, all it does is provides the same solution, just without any of the additional robustness. My answer body specifically states, 'The following example switches to codepage `1252`, West European Latin, (as also suggested in the comments by Gerhard), if not that already.' There's absolutely no need, even if he was to post his comment as an answer, to reject a more robust and complete answer in favor of that anyhow. That said, you are free to change your mind if another answer is posted, all it will do is toggle, not leave both of them marked.

Comment: @Lex, You can mark Compo's answer as correct. I understand that my shortened version does solve your issue, but it boils down to setting to the correct codepage. Remember, though this answer might seem more complicated, we all have our own unique ways and Compo uses the method to execute commands without relying on the path variables.

Comment: @Gerhard: Thank you for this comment - I accepted the answer. I've also added my current working code to the starting post if someone else will ever be in the same need.

Comment: As @aschipfl suggested I moved my "edits" from the starting post to the whole new one.

Answer (score 0):

The answer (as suggested by @Gerhard and @Compo): it was the wrong code page.

Below is my current working batch code if someone else will ever be in the same need (*to convert inverted ATASCII characters in ATARI BASIC code*).

It converts defined set of characters (*you can add more / delete some - just modify strings and the total number of characters*) and make comments more visible by adding lines at the start and at the end of each one.

```
@ECHO off

rem --------------------------------------------------
rem CHECK FOR THE SOURCE FILE
rem --------------------------------------------------

IF "%~1"=="" GOTO :End

rem --------------------------------------------------
rem SET THE CODE PAGE
rem --------------------------------------------------

CHCP 1252 > NUL

rem --------------------------------------------------
rem DEFINE THE SET OF CHARACTERS TO CONVERT
rem --------------------------------------------------

SET "input_set_of_chars= Ł¤§¨cŞ«¬­R°+˛ł´u¸ą»Ľ˝ľÁÂĂÄĹĆÇČÉĘËĚÍÎĎĐŃŇÓÔŐÖ×ŘŮÚř"
SET "output_set_of_chars= #$'()*+,-.0123456789;<=>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZx"
SET "number_of_chars=52"

rem --------------------------------------------------
rem CONVERT EACH LINE OF THE SOURCE FILE
rem --------------------------------------------------

(FOR /f "delims=" %%i in (%~1) DO (
    SET "line=%%i"
    CALL :ConvertASCII
))> "%~n1-converted%~x1"
GOTO :End

rem --------------------------------------------------
rem START OF THE CONVERT SUBROUTINE
rem --------------------------------------------------

:ConvertASCII
SETLOCAL enableDelayedExpansion

rem --------------------------------------------------
rem IF THE LINE IS NOT A COMMENT THEN DO NOT CONVERT
rem --------------------------------------------------

IF "!line!"=="!line: REM =!" GOTO :LoopEnd

rem --------------------------------------------------
rem MAKE COMMENT LINE A LITTLE MORE VISIBLE
rem --------------------------------------------------

SET "line=!line: REM = REM ----------!----------"

rem --------------------------------------------------
rem CONVERT ALL DEFINED CHARACTERS
rem --------------------------------------------------

SET "counter=0"
:LoopStart
SET "input_char=!input_set_of_chars:~%counter%,1!"
SET "output_char=!output_set_of_chars:~%counter%,1!"
SET "line=!line:%input_char%=%output_char%!"
SET /a counter+=1
IF "!counter!"=="!number_of_chars!" GOTO :LoopEnd
GOTO :LoopStart

rem --------------------------------------------------
rem ECHO THE CURRENT LINE AND EXIT SUBROUTINE
rem --------------------------------------------------

:LoopEnd   
ECHO.!line!
ENDLOCAL 
EXIT /b 0

:End
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64322513/unexpected-results-while-replacing-single-characters-in-a-text-file#comment113743067_64322513), it is actually not really a code page issue, because you have got [ATASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATASCII) encoding in your `*.bas` files. For converting such files to avoid inverted glyphs, I would use a language that can easily read the file in binary mode and subtract `0x80` from every byte whose value is greater than or equal to `0x80`.

Anyway, if you do want to replace the characters left over from your already performed conversion process (`Ć`, `Ç`, `Ň`, `Ô`, with codes `0x8F`, `0x80`, `0xD5`, `0xE2`, resp., as per your active [code page 852](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_852)), I would do it the following way, applying [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) during any conversion activities, because this defines the character set of the original IBM PC, also known as OEM font, where there should not occur any unwanted character conversion in the background:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=%~dp0."                & rem // (full path to target directory)
set "_SOURCE=source.txt"          & rem // (name of source file)
set "_RETURN=return.txt"          & rem // (name of return file)
set "_FILTER=^[0-9][0-9]*  *REM " & rem /* (`findstr` search expression to filter
                                    rem     for specific lines; `^`  means all) */

rem // Store current code page:
for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%P in ('chcp') do for /F %%C in ("%%P") do set "$CP=%%C"
rem // Set code page to OEM in order to avoid unwanted character conversions:
> nul chcp 437

rem /* Specify character replacements; the `forfiles` command supports substitution
rem    of hex codes like `0xHH`, so you can specify special characters by their code
rem    in order to avoid having to embed them into this script, which might in turn
rem    lead to problems due to dependencies on the current code page; each `0x22`
rem    represents a `"` to enclose each replacement expression within quotes; each
rem    of the following replacement expression is `"` + char. + `=` + char. +`"`: */
for /F "delims=" %%R in ('
    forfiles /P "%~dp0." /M "%~nx0" /C ^
        "cmd /C echo 0x220x8F=F0x22 0x220x80=G0x22 0x220xD5=R0x22 0x220xE2=T0x22"
') do set "RPL=%%R"

rem // Change into target directory:
pushd "%_ROOT%" && (
    rem // Write into return file:
    > "%_RETURN%" (
        rem /* Read from source file, temporarily precede each line with line number
        rem    followed by a `:` in order to not lose blank lines: */
        for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" "%_SOURCE%"') do (
            rem // Store current line:
            set "LINE=%%L"
            rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid troubles with `!`:
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            rem // Remove temporary line number prefix:
            set "LINE=!LINE:*:=!"
            rem // Filter for lines that are subject to the replacements:
            cmd /V /C echo(^^!LINE^^!| > nul findstr /R /I /C:"!_FILTER!" && (
                rem // Perform replacements one after another:
                for %%R in (%RPL%) do if defined LINE set "LINE=!LINE:%%~R!"
            )
            rem // Return resulting line:
            echo(!LINE!
            endlocal
        )
    )
    rem // Return from target directory:
    popd
)

rem // Restore former code page:
if defined $CP > nul chcp %$CP%

endlocal
exit /B
```

This approach performs the character replacements only in lines that begin with: a decimal number, followed by one or more <kbd>SPACEs</kbd>, followed by `REM` in a case-insensitive manner, followed by a <kbd>SPACE</kbd>.

---

Here is now a script that truly converts [ATASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATASCII) characters in `REM` comments in your Atari Basic (`*.bas`) file, using [`certutil`](https://ss64.com/nt/certutil.html) for converting the binary character codes:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_TARGET=%~dp0."               & rem // (full path to target directory)
set "_SOURCE=source.txt"           & rem // (name of source file)
set "_RETURN=return.txt"           & rem // (name of return file)
set "_FILTER=^[0-9][0-9]*  *REM "  & rem /* (`findstr` search expression to filter
                                     rem     for specific lines; `^`  means all) */
set "_TEMPFN=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%" & rem // (path and base name of temporary file)

rem // Change into target directory:
pushd "%_TARGET%" && (
    rem // Write into return file:
    > "%_RETURN%" (
        rem /* Read from source file, temporarily precede each line with line number
        rem    followed by a `:` in order to not lose blank lines: */
        for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N "^" "%_SOURCE%"') do (
            rem // Store current line:
            set "LINE=%%L"
            rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid troubles with `!`:
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            rem // Remove temporary line number prefix:
            set "LINE=!LINE:*:=!"
            rem // Filter for lines that are subject to the replacements:
            cmd /V /C echo(^^!LINE^^!| > nul findstr /R /I /C:"!_FILTER!" && (
                rem // Found a line, hence write it to temporary file:
                (> "!_TEMPFN!.tmp" echo(!LINE!) && (
                    rem // Convert temporary file to hex dump file:
                    > nul certutil -f -encodehex "!_TEMPFN!.tmp" "!_TEMPFN!.cnv" 4 && (
                        rem // Write to temporary file:
                        (> "!_TEMPFN!.tmp" (
                            rem // Read hex dump file line by line:
                            for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%T in ("!_TEMPFN!.cnv") do (
                                rem // Reset buffer, loop through hex values:
                                set "BUFF= " & for %%H in (%%T) do (
                                    rem // Determine new hex value, append it to buffer:
                                    set "HEX=%%H" & set /A "FIG=0x!HEX:~,1!-0x8"
                                    if !FIG! lss 0 (
                                        rem // Value was < 0x80, hence keep it:
                                        set "BUFF=!BUFF! !HEX!"
                                    ) else (
                                        rem // Value was >= 0x80, hence subtract 0x80:
                                        set "BUFF=!BUFF! !FIG!!HEX:~1!"
                                    )
                                )
                                echo(!BUFF:~2!
                            )
                        )) && (
                            > nul certutil -f -decodehex "!_TEMPFN!.tmp" "!_TEMPFN!.cnv" 4 && (
                                type "!_TEMPFN!.cnv"
                            ) || echo(!LINE!
                        ) || echo(!LINE!
                    ) || echo(!LINE!
                ) || echo(!LINE!
            ) || (
                rem // Return resulting line:
                echo(!LINE!
            )
            endlocal
        )
    )
    rem // Clean up temporary files:
    del "%_TEMPFN%.tmp" "%_TEMPFN%.cnv"
    rem // Return from target directory:
    popd
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. At this moment I do not have (or knowledge about) the access to other language so I used batch as "quick fix". I do not know if subtraction of `0x80` from "every byte" would be the best way in my case - my Atari Basic code is not a "pure one" and has a few inserts in Assembly language represented by characters from full range of ATASCII and I would prefer to not change them. All comments are in their own lines so they are easy to separate from the rest of the code and they are probably the only thing that needs this conversion (to be able to read / understand them).

Comment: I see, so a binary read would not help; is there a way to clearly identify these ATASCII comments to be converted? if so, the conversion could be done only for the applicable lines then…

Comment: I've presented an example of such line in the comment just below the one you have linked: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64322513/unexpected-results-while-replacing-single-characters-in-a-text-file#comment113743189_64322513) - it says `100 REM PRINT` (after conversion). In the batch code in my own answer I've already implemented skip for all lines which are not the comments: `IF "!line!"=="!line: REM =!" GOTO :LoopEnd`.

Comment: Alright, I just edited my answer and established a filter for such lines, hence others remain untouched…